# Error while calibrating stereo camera

Tags: python, computer-vision, opencv3.0, camera-calibration

I want to calibrate my tow camera using openCv. i used the code blew but i get this error

code:

```
TERMINATION_CRITERIA = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS , 30,0.001)
(_, _, _, _, _, rotationMatrix, translationVector, _, _) = cv2.stereoCalibrate(
        objectPoints, leftImagePoints, rightImagePoints,
        leftCameraMatrix, leftDistortionCoefficients,
        rightCameraMatrix, rightDistortionCoefficients,
        imageSize, None, None, None, None,TERMINATION_CRITERIA,
        cv2.CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC)
```

> error:
>        cv2.CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC,TERMINATION_CRITERIA)
>       SystemError: new style getargs format but argument is not a tuple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to switch your last two arguments according to the [documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html)

```
TERMINATION_CRITERIA = (cv2.TERM_CRITERIA_EPS , 30,0.001)
(_, _, _, _, _, rotationMatrix, translationVector, _, _) = cv2.stereoCalibrate(
        objectPoints, leftImagePoints, rightImagePoints,
        leftCameraMatrix, leftDistortionCoefficients,
        rightCameraMatrix, rightDistortionCoefficients,
        imageSize, None, None, None, None,
        TERMINATION_CRITERIA, cv2.CALIB_FIX_INTRINSIC) #switched<>
```

Comment: Then I believe the issue lies with an arugment that we cannot see the definition of. Check your arguments that should be tuples and ensure they are tuples with `type(var)`